# Angular 2+ conditional template variables

Tags: angular, angular2-template, viewchild

I have a set of inputs with a template variable `#input`. The disable status of the inputs changes based on user input. I grabbing the current set of inputs via:

```
@ViewChildren('input') inputs: QueryList<any>;
...
const inputs = this.inputs.toArray();
...
```

With what I'm doing a disabled input blocks me. So I need to remove the template variable if that input is disabled. I thought about placing an `ng-container` and showing/hiding but won't work for a multitude of reasons. Is it possible have a conditional template or tell the `@ViewChildren` to conditionally ignore a child?

Comment: why can't you `this.inputs.toArray().filter(...)`?

Comment: @Reactgular can you make this an answer? That worked perfectly.

Comment: You are creating "inputs" variable as @viewchildren, plus as a const assigning the array of that inputs. Really it allows you to execute your program? or is it showing an error for variable names? (ambiguity in name!)